# Javascript function not working with an array

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onclick

i have this function which loops through an array of check boxes checking if the boxes value is equal to something in a text box, i dont know whats wrong.

```
function checkValue(contain)  {  
        var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");  
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {  
        if (boxes[i].name == "vote[]") {  
            if (boxes[i].value.indexOf(contain.value) != -1) {  
            boxes[i].checked = true;  
        }  
    }   
}  
}
```

and this is how i call it

```
 OnClick="uncheckAll(); checkValue(document.getElementsByName("countrylist"));"
```

this code is in side a echo in php which is like this echo ' ';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot nest the same type of quotes in HTML.

```
OnClick="uncheckAll(); checkValue(document.getElementsByName(\'countrylist\'));"
```

Simply escape the single quotes as shown as PHP provides an easy escape mechanism.

Comment: as said, im using php to echo it in single quotation marks so if i were to use single quotation marks my php would error

Comment: @Ryan, then escape them with `\'` http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

the `contain` argument you're passing is an array not a string. that could be the problem?

Comment: but the value "contain" is not an array its the word "UK"

Comment: the argument "contain" is the return value of this call `document.getElementsByName("countrylist")` getElementsByName returns an array of elements with that name

Comment: yes, or you should pass document.getElementsByName("countrylist")[0] to the function. either way should help. also, as InsDel suggested, you can't nest javascript double quotes inside html double quotes, so change them for single quotes `document.getElementsByName('countrylist')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I think your javascript might be having an issue with the name of your field being vote[].

Does it ever pass the condition:

```
if (boxes[i].name == "vote[]") {
```

Comment: yes, i have a function to check all boxes so i modified it to the above results, but yes the check all function works

Answer (score 0):

1) Update the inlince call to use single quotes:

```
checkValue(document.getElementsByName('countrylist'))
```

2) Use document.getElementsByName to make the function little better:

```
function checkValue(contain)  
{           
    var boxes = document.getElementsByName("vote[]");
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) 
    {     
        boxes[i].checked = (boxes[i].value == contain.value);
    }   
}
```